# trying to get the members without logout time using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this....

```
 SELECT member_Firstname, member_Lastname,
          visit_DateTime, visit_Status, visit_Logout_DateTime
          FROM members, visits
          WHERE members.member_Id = visits.member_Id
          AND members.member_Active LIKE 'y%' AND visits.visit_Status = 'accepted'  AND visits.visit_Date = '2011-11-02' Order by visit_DateTime desc limit 100;
```

it was giving results like this......

```
 firstname     lastname     status        visit_Logout_DateTime        visit_datetime      
-------------  --------      -------        ---------------------    ----------------
  rob           peter       accepted                                   2011-11-02 08:09:34                          
  peter          chan           accepted                                 2011-11-02 06:09:34
  rock         sam          accepted         2011-11-02 09:08:45    
  rob           peter           accepted          2011-11-02 07:09:07     2011-11-02 08:09:34
```

i want to get the members with `status = accepted` and dont have  `visit_Logout_DateTime`

would any one pls help on this....
many thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT member_Firstname, member_Lastname,
          visit_DateTime, visit_Status, visit_Logout_DateTime
          FROM members, visits
          WHERE members.member_Id = visits.member_Id AND visits.visit_Logout_DateTime is null
          AND members.member_Active LIKE 'y%' AND visits.visit_Status = 'accepted'  AND visits.visit_Date = '2011-11-02' Order by visit_DateTime desc limit 100;
```

does this work?